# SetFloat for animator not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

The function SetFloat() does not recognize the speed when my character moves in the x axis, but still recognizes the y axis.
I don't understand why the player´s x velocity is not signed to the "Speed" float created in the animator

```
public float acceleration;
public bool isGrounded = true;
public float jumpHeight;
Animator anim;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded == true){
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (0 , jumpHeight);
        isGrounded = false;
    }

    if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y == 0){
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x));

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
        transform.position += new Vector3 (acceleration * Time.deltaTime , 0.0f, 0.0f);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (5,5,5);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)){
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-5,5,5);
        transform.position -= new Vector3 (acceleration * Time.deltaTime , 0.0f , 0.0f);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question is still relevant but, if you want to set a float in the animator, you can't use transform.position. transform.position doesn't change any Rigidbody values, in order to do that you would want to move the Rigidbody using rigidbody.MovePosition or rigidbody.AddForce.

I suggest using rigidbody.MovePosition because you don't have to write much code.

The way i do it is i don't use Input.GetKey because it's quite sloppy and doesn't work as well as Input.GetAxis:

```
function Update()
{
float keyboardX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * acceleration * Time.deltaTime;

rigid.MovePosition(keyboardX);

anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x));
}
```

This should work. Again, i'm not sure how relevant this is.